# how do i create new checkboxes from xml file target

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

if i have a new target in a xml file like

```
<target name="main" depends="init">
 <antcall target="Exec_Install_abc" /></target>
```

where "Install abc" is the new target. If i want to load this xml file and if i detect any new target in my xml file, i would want to automatically add a new checkbox to the graphical user interface permanently with such a following code:

```
ExecinstallabcCheckBox.Content = "Exec Install Abc";
```

it sounds like i need to do xml parsing. but i am not sure if it is the correct way to do. It means to say i will ultimately edit my xaml and xaml.cs file. I would also need to remove the "underscores" and put spaces in between the words as required. I am a little confused on where to start and how to go about doing it. Would appreciate if someone can guide me to start me off.Thanks.

Edit1:
I will be able to add a checkbox to my graphical user interface if i click a "Refresh" Button on the present graphical user interface. This allows the graphical user interface to be refreshed and show the new checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can tell you how to go about it, but not exactly in code completely. Because that will a lot of code. I can show you the way though and here is how it goes:

The easiest way for you to do this will be first parse your xml. You can use linq-to-xml for this. [Example](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/introduction-to-linq-simple-xml-parsing).

After this, you can use the `String.Replace` method to remove the underscores and add spaces. With something like:

```
string formattedCaption = checkBoxCaptionExtractedFromXml.Replace('_', ' ');
```

This will solve how will you load the xml. Now you can create a window and declare a `ListView` with a `CheckBox` as `GridViewColumn` that is binded to a class which contains the name and a bool to represent the state of the `CheckBox`. Like this:

```
public class MyCheckBoxes
{
    public bool State { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

You have to fill this class with the check box captions you want to display. And you can declare your `ListView` like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="myCheckBoxColumns" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="250" Header="Some Header">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding State}" Content="{Binding Caption}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And then assigning the filled list of `MyCheckBoxes` in window loaded event:

```
List<MyCheckBoxes> listBoxes = new List<MyCheckBoxes>();
..
// Fill listBoxes with date in constructor or before the below
// mentioned statement in window loaded event...
..
// In window loaded event...
myCheckBoxColumns.ItemsSource = listBoxes;
```

This should do for you I believe. Feel free to ask anything if it is not understandable.

Comment: thanks for your help. i am currently studying your algorithm at work right now.. will update u if i encounter problems

Comment: i just have a question regarding the parsing. if lets say previously i already have some targets that i already hard coded into the check box and for example it is also in the form of <antcall target="Exec_Install_Xyz"/> how do i ensure that Exec_Install_Xyz is not coded into a checkbox? i have plenty of such targets to worry about

Comment: and also how do i know this "Exec_Install_Abc" is a new target in the huge xml file?

Comment: You can make a dictionary of the check box captions, and check that dictionary before adding it to the `listBoxes`.

Comment: hi yogesh, can i have an example on having a dictionary? and also... i have a tab control with a few tab items already. i wish to put this listview into a tab item. i suppose it is possible right? because right now all my tab items contain a grid and if i implement this list view, i will be confused

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that xml is stored at location "c:\test.xml" and has content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<target name="main" depends="init">
 <antcall target="Exec_Install_abc" />
</target>
```

So, you should put XmlDataProvider to your xaml as static resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider Source="c:\\test.xml" x:Key="xDoc"/>
    <self:UnderscoresConverter x:Key="UnderscoresConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then use Binding for Content property in checkbox:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource xDoc}, XPath=target/antcall/@target, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource UnderscoresConverter}}"/>
```

And don't forget about converter which replaces underscores (also put it to resources, as I've done above):

```
public class UnderscoresConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString().Replace('_', ' ');
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**EDITED**

Consider more complicated case. Our xml document looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<targets>
    <target name="main" depends="init">
        <antcall target="Exec_Install_abc" />
    </target>
    <target name="main" depends="init">
        <antcall target="Ololo_jesus_christ" />
    </target>
    <target name="main" depends="init">
        <antcall target="One_____more target" />
    </target>
</targets>
```

Now we have a lot of targets and have to create a lot of check boxes. Okay, we need ItemsControl. The ItemsSource for our ItemsControl will be a collection of attributes *target* selected from *antcall* nodes (XmlAttribute objects). Then we define a DataTemplate, put CheckBox inside it, and bind Content property to Value property via converter that removes underscore symbols.

Despite apparent complexity, the result code is rather simple:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xDoc}, XPath=targets/target/antcall/@target}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource UnderscoresConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: hi alex, i would like to find out where do u actually put the <Window.Resources> ... </Window.Resources> in the xaml file?

Comment: oh yes btw, if i have many targets to be implemented into the check box, can this work?

Comment: What do you mean "many targets into check box". One checkbox should display a bunch of targets or every target should be placed into separate checkbox?

Comment: @alex zhevzhik sorry if it was unclear.. what i meant was. If i have many new targets in the xml file to generate, will the code above that you mentioned be able to generate a checkbox for each target? means 4 new targets = 4 new check box

Comment: hi alex, thanks for you reply. i think i roughly get your code. i have this issue though. <self:UnderscoresConverter x:Key="UnderscoresConverter"/>
the "self" here is a undeclared namespace. is there something i am missing? also how do i set a dictionary to check if these targets have been generated into a checkbox before?

Comment: "self" is reference to namespace from your assembly where UnderscoresConverter is defined. Here(http://pastie.org/1573686) you could find declaration of "self" namespace (my UnderscoresConverter class is inside Test namespace). Dictionary? Actually I don't understand the question. Besides I don't intent to supply comprehensive solution of your problem right here right now. I just give you direction to move. As you haven't provided any details of your code's infrastructure, I've implemented the most quick and simple solution. Any problems or restrictions? Provide them in new question.

Comment: hi alex, i saw your snippet. what does it mean by clr-namespace:Test? what is the Test here

Comment: Test is namespace where my classes are located. I defined class Test.UnderscoresConverter (like System.String class).